# Swagger HK2 service reification failed

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, swagger, java-9, hk2

This application use Swagger (swagger-jersey2-jaxrs, 1.5.18), Spring-boot (spring-boot-starter-jersey, 2.0.1.RELEASE) and Java 9. When application ran Swagger UI loads without an issue. But I can see following warning in the logs. Appreciate any idea to solve this. I have tried upgrading versions but couldn't help.

```
2018-04-17 14:27:19.792  WARN 24810 --- [nio-7070-exec-5] org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors     : The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [javax.servlet.ServletConfig] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in javax.servlet.ServletConfig class.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:192)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:694)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.igdCacheCompute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1186)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$400(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1177)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1260)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:581)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:590)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.lambda$new$0(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.lambda$new$0(Cache.java:193)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:249)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache.apply(Cache.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.lambda$getValueProvider$0(DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.serviceImpl(ServletContainer.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:584)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:525)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=javax.servlet.ServletConfig
    contracts={javax.servlet.ServletConfig}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=null
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=232
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=982366577
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:705)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.igdCacheCompute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1186)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$400(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1177)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1260)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:581)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:590)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.lambda$new$0(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.lambda$new$0(Cache.java:193)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:249)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache.apply(Cache.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.lambda$getValueProvider$0(DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.serviceImpl(ServletContainer.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:584)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:525)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with swagger, but this error indicates that some code somewhere was trying to inject a ServletConfig and that ServletConfig doesn't have a proper constructor that can be seen by hk2

Comment: I use same dependencies and I get the same issue. I only get this exception the first time when I get swagger.json with web browser, like http://localhost:8080/my-rest/swagger.json. Maybe we need to rise a bug ticket on swagger-jersey2-jaxrs?

Comment: Exception see when first time loading the swagger UI. Also warning can see if refresh the web page.

Answer (score 1):

This warning is caused by swagger-jersey-jaxrs2 1.5.X expecting a ServletConfig object in ApiListingResource.

Fix:

1. Create the following class:

```
// Alternate implementation of swagger-jersey-jaxrs2's ApiListingResource class. 
// Needed to support running jersey as a servlet filter without any warnings from the jersey class analyzer.
@Path("/swagger.{type:json|yaml}")
public class FilterApiListingResource extends BaseApiListingResource {

    @Inject ServletConfig servletConfig;
    
    @Context ServletContext context;

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/yaml"})
    @ApiOperation(value = "The swagger definition in either JSON or YAML", hidden = true)
    public Response getListing(
            @Context Application app,
            @Context HttpHeaders headers,
            @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
            @PathParam("type") String type) {
        return getListingJsonResponse(app, context, servletConfig, headers, uriInfo);
    }
}
```

2. Instead of registering ApiListingResource in jersey ResourceConfig register FilterApiListingResource

Deeper explanation:
This issue has to do with an interaction between swagger-jersey-jaxrs2, jersey and Spring boot.

Here is what is happening according to my understanding:

1. Jersey calls hk2 to supply a ServletConfig object.
2. Spring boots jersey integration has a hk2 bridge, so spring boot ioc supplies back a FilterConfig object.
3. JerseyClassAnalyzer attempts to reify the supplied FilterConfig object to a ServletConfig, but FilterConfig does not implement ServletConfig so JerseyClassAnalyzer throws a warning then injects the FilterConfig into swagger-jersey-jaxrs2 anyway.
4. swagger-jersey-jaxrs2 passes the FilterConfig to swagger core (transitive dependency of swagger-jersey-jaxrs2) which works anyways since swagger core supports running jersey as a filter.

I believe swagger-jersey-jaxrs2 could fix this warning by refactoring to be dependent on Jerseys WebConfig interface instead of ServletConfig. Webconfig is how jersey can abstractly refer to an object which implents either ServletConfig or FilterConfig.

This works because FilterApiListingResource skips the reification process of the JerseyClassAnalyzer and uses Spring ioc to inject the FilterConfig as a ServletConfig.

Answer (score 0):

please insert 2.26 for jersey-hk2  in pom.xml file. I tried that and it worked for me

Comment: added, still: org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to spring-boot-starter-jersey to version 2.0.3.RELEASE. Then this warning disappeared.